# Why does the output comes out different as both of the c++ statements are doing the same operation

Tags: c++, string, char, cout, typeid

```
string k="*";
cout<<typeid(k).name()<<endl;
```

Output: `Ss`

```
cout<<typeid("*").name()<<endl;
```

Output: `A2_c`

What is the difference between these two that causes the output to come out different? And what is the meaning of the output?

Answer (score 3):

The `k` in `string k = "*"` is an instance of the `std::string` class, while `"*"` is a `const char[2]` array due to being a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). `k` is constructed from the contents of the array, but it is not itself such an array.

Also, note that `typeid()`...

> ... returns an implementation defined null-terminated character string containing the name of the type. **No guarantees are given**, in particular, the returned string can be identical for several types and change between invocations of the same program.

For more info, check [this reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).